# How is the priority chosen while constructing the Huffman Tree?

Tags: algorithm, huffman-code

Suppose my characters and their frequencies are as follows:

```
Char    Freq.
 a       1
 b       2
 c       3
 d       4
 e       5
 f       6
 g       7
 h       8
```

When constructing a tree, at step 2 we have this:

```
   [3]     [3]   [4]   [5]   [6]   [7]   [8]
   / \      c     d     e     f     g     h
  /   \
[1]   [2]
 a     b
```

Now, since we have two 3s, how can we determine the priority of them?

In the Huffman Coding this is considered as:

```
[3]    [3]     [4]   [5]   [6]   [7]   [8]
 c     / \      d     e     f     g     h   
      /   \
    [1]   [2]
     a     b
```

## **Why?**

Answer (score 1):

What's the difference? Ignoring `d` through `h` for the moment, in the first case you'd get

```
a = 00
b = 01
c = 1
```

and in the second case,

```
a = 10
b = 11
c = 0
```

As long as `c` is at the same height in the final tree, its code will have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

I would take c with bigger priority (shorter code). This would be in-line with the basic principle of Huffman trees: priority/shorter code for immediate results and lower priority for more parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Your case is not interesting.  The assignments of 0's and 1's to the branches is arbitrary, so the choice you outline results in the same code, i.e. the same code lengths, either way.

There are however interesting cases where you face a choice of three or more groups with the same total frequency and different shapes.  Any choice will result in the same overall optimality, i.e. exactly the same number of total bits to encode the provided symbols at the provided frequencies.  However the choices can result in different shape trees with different combinations of bit lengths.  Then such a choice can be made to arrive at deeper or shallower trees, depending on what is desired.